# Flutter generic function for .fromJson factory

Tags: json, flutter, mobile

I want to make a flexible json decoding function that takes the response body from an api and converts it into object instances using the factory function `.fromJson()`.

I also want the function to be `Generic` so that it can accept every element that has a factory method `.fromJson()`

For generatic the code i use `JsonSerializable` a package suggested in the flutter guides so i hope that's not the problem.

This is the abstract class that decodable objects have to implement:

```dart
abstract class WireObject {
  WireObject.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json);
}
```

This is an example object:

```dart
import 'package:iregistro_flutter/core/models/enums/absence_type.dart';
import 'package:iregistro_flutter/core/models/interfaces/wire_object.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'absence_wire.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Absence implements WireObject {
  DateTime date;
  String id;
  bool justified;
  AbsenceType type;

  Absence({
    required this.date,
    required this.justified,
    required this.id,
    required this.type,
  });

  @override //idk if i need to override the method
  factory Absence.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AbsenceFromJson(json);
}
```

And this is my function to decode json into object.

```dart
List<T> parseListOfObjects<T extends WireObject>(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  final documents = parsed
      .map((json) => T.fromJson(json))
      .toList();
  return documents;
}
```

Thanks for the help, i'm fairly new to flutter and i apologize in advance if i had made a silly mistake.